# Different performance level for N2 sku across different regions for GCP

Tags: performance, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been running performance benchmarks for my application in GKE using a custom sized N2 series sku over the past week.  For some reason, I consistently get 25% faster performance in US-West-1 compared to US-East-4 for the same sized sku (30 cores with 240GB RAM).  Is is possible that GCP is just running hotter in US-East-4?  Can't think of any other possible reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please take a look at [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you share the details of the benchmark test you are running? Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!